# Note on "What should I do when someone answers my question?" page that upvoting requires 15 reputation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, up-votes, help

The help page [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) says:

> The first thing you should do when someone answers your question is vote on it, like any other user does.

However, new users (which is probably the primary target group for this help page) may not have the [*Vote Up* privilege](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) yet (as it requires 15 reputation).

I guess they’ll see some kind of error message when trying to upvote before they have enough rep, but I think it should also be mentioned on this help page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed that line to just say:

> The first thing you should do after reading someone's answer to your question is vote on the answer, like any other user (with sufficient reputation) does.

Since upvoting and downvoting require different amounts of reputation, just mentioning that voting requires rep seems sufficient here. (And yes, if a user who doesn't have enough rep tries to vote – or perform any other rep-based action – they get an error telling them the amount of rep required, with a link to the privilege page for whatever they were trying to do.)