# The meaning of "it" and other small gripes about "What should I do when someone answers my question?"

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, help-center

First sentence of Help Center page [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers):

> The first thing you should do when someone answers your question is vote on it, like any other user does.

The pronoun *it* must be referring to a noun... which one? *answers* is a verb here.

Other issues with the sentence:

1. Misplaced sense of urgency: *the first thing to do* is to vote! Not to read the answer carefully and check whether the solution works.
2. New users [can't vote anyway](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220527/).

By the way, the link "To accept an answer:" points to meta.SO. It redirects correctly, but...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I changed the first sentence of that article to say:

> The first thing you should do after reading someone's answer to your question is vote on the answer, like any other user (with sufficient reputation) does.

I'm not sure why you were seeing the accepted answer link pointing to MSO rather than MSE; that link got rewritten when we did the split, and showed the correct URL when I went to edit the article.

At any rate, the page is updated.